# Dynamic API namespace change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got an application which needs to change the API namespace dependent on the state. To illustrate the point, here are some api endpoints:

```
/groups     (lists all groups)
/foo/users  (lists all users in group foo)
/bar/users  (lists all users in group bar)
```

I navigate to the `foo` route, then click on the users link. How can I change the namespace for the users dynamically?

**Update**
Here is some code. I'm still figuring Ember out, and my JS knowledge is also a bit shaky.

I use the ember-data RESTAdapter which I've subclassed. Most importantly I have this:

```
App.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:5001"
});
```

This works quite well, so I thought of putting the following into the controller

```
App.GroupRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    App.RESTAdapter.reopen({url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000", namespace: 'blah'});
    controller.set('model', App.User.find());
  }
});
```

But that makes no difference. From my understanding it makes the most sense to change the namespace when the controller is initialized (since at that stage I already know what the namespace should be), but am not sure how to make it happen

**Update 2**

I've managed to get it to work with the following code. Is that the best way of doing it?

```
var id = window.App.__container__.lookup('controller:group').get('id');
App.RESTAdapter.prototype.namespace = id;``
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far? Or simply more code of your setup?

Comment: Would you not just set the model property on FooUsersRoute and BarUsersRoute to return the users in each group respectively?